# android paypal SDK : merchant does not accept payments of this type

Tags: android, paypal

I use new Android Mobile SDK for PayPal.

Live using. And when I post money to the existing app with existing Client ID, I receive a error :

{
"name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT",
"message":"Unauthorized payment",
"information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT",
"debug_id":"590ffad92140e"
}

I added CLIENT_ID of the app 
I have also the SECRET_ID, but I couldn't find the method where I can set it.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the merchant account has Pro permissions. also, be sure the app has been approved. The app has basic permissions until you submit it for approval.

Comment: Ok, but we have Business account type. Is it enough to successful proceeding ?

Comment: yes but to accept credit card payments in the live environment your account must be approved for PayPal Payments Pro. https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro

Comment: @PP_MSI_KevinG, in my case account type is Pro and also approved by PayPal, But still i get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also happen if you're trying to pay yourself. (Receiving account == sending account).

Also note that `client_secret` is for **server side code only**. For example, it's used when you [verify a payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/). Putting a secret into your app is like handing out your account password, since anyone can decompile the app and take whatever strings are there.